# Run Generate Controller command from a Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I know the basic command to create controllers in Rails is to use Rails generate controller

But in the code I see something like this structure below and was wondering how to do that?

The structure looks like this:

[image]

and the generated code looks like this, I need something similar:

```
module Performance
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
  end
end


module Performance
  class GroupsController < BaseController
    def show
    end

    def index
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

To generate namespaced controller you should type, for example:

```
rails g controller performance/base
```

Comment: Ok I tried it now but it didn't generate that "module" stuff, I said for example rails g controller father/child   and it created a directory called father, and a child_controller inside it but the source of that child_controller doesn't have "module" in it.