# Namespaced controllers and classes in Modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have done this command:  `rails g controller father/child` and it has genersted this for me:

```
class Father::ChildController < ApplicationController
end
```

**But** my goal is to have this:

```
module Father
  class ChildController < ApplicationController

  end
end
```

Are these two the same? or I should use generate controller in a different way to achive that module like syntax?

Comment: Thanks, so rails generates the first syntax for me. So after that I can just hand type and change it to the second syntax. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can, but make sure to add `::ApplicationController`, else it will work like `Father::ApplicationController`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They not the same. The second one is equivalent to the following:

```
class Father::ChildController < Father::ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: oh Thanks, another person said they are the same. I really need to generate it like the second syntax. Can you show me what to do to generate the code for second syntax?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a bit to fast with my comment, check my next comment to see how you can use it the way you want..

Comment: @Tim Ok so it is getting a little complicated. Please take a look at the question I asked in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153286/run-generate-controller-command-from-a-module   The second syntax was my goal to achieve, so how can I do that? Looks like what I was told to do doesn't generate the syntax we need.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.. You cannot generate the syntax like that.. You have to edit it after generating.. If you edit it like the code you show in the other post, it should work..