# What's the correct way to declare a controller class inside of a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, controller

I have had multiple projects in where I had to add a controller inside of a module for namespace and different users reasons. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153814/namespaced-controllers-and-classes-in-modules) I had a better understanding of the difference but don't really know **which one is best**. The thing is that I have always written it like this:

```
# Version A: app/controllers/example_module/example_controller.rb
module ExampleModule
  class ExampleController < ExampleModuleBaseController
  end
end

# app/controllers/example_module/example_module_base_controller.rb
class ExampleModule::ExampleModuleBaseController < ApplicationController
end
```

When you run:

```
rails g controller ExampleModule/Example
```

it creates:

```
# app/controllers/example_module/example_controller.rb
class ExampleModule::ExampleController < ApplicationController
end
```

After correcting the inheritance it would be:

```
# Version B: app/controllers/example_module/example_controller.rb
class ExampleModule::ExampleController < ExampleModule::ExampleModuleBaseController
end
```

**Which version is the correct one? Version A or Version B?**

Comment: Both versions are correct. But in version A you must first write `ExampleModule`.

Comment: If both versions are correct (and I'm assuming the same) is there a convention? I feel that Version A is easier to read.

Comment: Version B. I like that style. No extra block needed.